# How can I resolve the RoR error shown below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[Signup form error from RoR tutorials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPvSM.png)
Please how can I resolve the error shown in the screenshot.

I'm just learning Ruby on Rails by Michael Hartl.

[Screenshot of my user controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqbKH.png)

Comment: please, write your controller code in question

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a code sample here, it looks like something in your User model that is causing this error.  Specifically look at line 26 and copy/paste the code for that whole method.

Comment: Agree that more details are needed. What's the context in which the error occurs? What are you trying to accomplish and what have you already  tried to fix the issue?